# Holes in drywall slightly too wide for screws

Tags: drill, hole

[image]

I drilled with 3/8" still bit as instructed, but the holes seem too large for the screws. I'm wondering what the best fix for this would be. Fill the holes up with wood glue and toothpicks and screw into that, or widen the holes to place anchors in and screw in there? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Putting screws directly into drywall, particularly the type shown in your photo, will rarely (if ever) work. The drywall is not strong or firm enough to hold screws without hollow-wall anchors of some sort.

You need to tell us more, however; if you want advice as to what sort of anchoring system you need. What is the reason you need to put screws in the wall?

Answer (score 1):

#### I'd use one of these.

They come in a few sizes too so you get the larger size if need be.

#### [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are hanging significant weight it is recommended you use a stud finder to find a stud, "real wood" as carpenters say, to support the load. The newer tapered drywall fasteners you show are ok, but not recommended for anything with decent weight. Use plastic anchors and (a trick) size your bit down one size from the recommended diameter, pump the hole with construction adhesive such as Liquid Nails, or Loctite, and gingerly drive the anchor in as not to bend it -- it will want to bend so tap it. Let the glue setup 24 hours before you put the screw in. This will beef up the load bearing characteristic of the anchor. Don't just screw into drywall without an anchoring system; time and moisture will cause the gypsum to eventually fail and the screw will pull out.